# How can I search in an UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I need to perform search in an html page displayed in a UIWebView control. The functionality I need is something that Safari has, when you hit command/ctrl F for searching the document for some word and the program highlights the hits for you. Is there any easy solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's been a long time since you asked this question, but it's still a pretty common question people have so I put together a sample project in case anyone else is asking the same question. The project is a super simple app that loads an HTML file and can search and highlight any keyword. You can download the sample project here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jietctrvrtnec28/TheSearcher.zip?dl=0

Scott

Edit: changed link above as the old one had broken.

Comment: The file is not available now..!

Comment: @Clement thanks for the heads up, I've fixed the broken link.

Comment: Many thanks Scott. I needed in swift with `WKWebView`, your sample code is a great help!!

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with javascript.  Check out the  "Find in this page" bookmarklet:
http://www.lifeclever.com/17-powerful-bookmarklets-for-your-iphone/

Something like that, combined with:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That what I figured out myself in the meantime, too. But the bookmarklet you have mentionded, doesn't works correctly, because it ruins the html if you search for something that can be found inside the html tag.

I need to use something like that:
http://james.padolsey.com/demos/misc/findAndReplace/