# Save the highlighting text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

I have searched for many days to do the folowing :

1. Highlight a text in UIWebView and save the highlight in iOS ( Core Data, ...) to highlight to second time the user lunch the app. How i ca, do this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can search and highlight the text using Javascript, [check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004094/how-can-i-search-in-an-uiwebview)

I've used that code and works perfectly.

If you want to "save" the highlighted text you can save the word or phrase to highlight in a plist file or in Core Data. So when you need to recover the highlights you simply pass the words or phrases to the Javascript function.

You may need to modify the code just a little, because it cleans the highlights everytime you want to highlight new words.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It not solve for the phrase which are repeating in a page. Like if user highlight "are", it will highlight all "are" in a page