# presentOpenInMenuFromRect not working DocumentHandler.h - QuickLook

Tags: ios, cordova, quicklook, presentviewcontroller

I'm using documenthandler cordova plugin in where if I click the button I get the pdf in the document handler from the url which works fine, so that I can save the pdf into iBooks.

Now, instead of opening the document in the viewer and clicking the share button and then click again to save into iBooks I need to be able to trigger the share button without opening the document. I know this can be done using `presentOpenInMenuFromRect` instead of `presentViewController`but it does not work for some reason, code below:

```
#import "DocumentHandler.h"

@implementation DocumentHandler

- (void)HandleDocumentWithURL:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
{
    CDVPluginResult *commandResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@""];

    __weak DocumentHandler* weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_queue_t asyncQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(asyncQueue, ^{

        NSDictionary* dict = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString* urlStr = dict[@"url"];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSData* dat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSString* fileName = [url lastPathComponent];
        NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
        NSURL* tmpFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
        [dat writeToURL:tmpFileUrl atomically:YES];
        weakSelf.fileUrl = tmpFileUrl;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            QLPreviewController* cntr = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
            cntr.delegate = weakSelf;
            cntr.dataSource = weakSelf;

            UIViewController* root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

            [root presentViewController:cntr animated:YES completion:nil];//this works fine and open the document with share button

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
            [root presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES]; // this doesn't work where
            //I want to see only sharing options
            //here are errors,one of them is /Property'view' not found on object of type ''DocumentHandler
        });


        [weakSelf.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:commandResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    });
}



#pragma mark - QLPreviewController data source

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - QLPreviewItem protocol

- (NSURL*)previewItemURL
{
    return self.fileUrl;
}

@end
```

I need help please :(

EDIT: see the image what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`presentOpenInMenuFromRect` is a `UIDocumentInteractionController` method. I do not think you are using one in this code, unless your root view controller is a `UIDocumentInteractionController`, which would be very very weird.

Instead of instantiating and presenting a `QLPreviewController`, instantiate an `UIDocumentInteractionController` and present the popover from the rect corresponding to the document's icon.

To do this, check out the [UIDocumentInteractionController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html). You'll see there is an `interactionControllerWithURL:` method that you can use to instantiate an `UIDocumentInteractionController` pointed at your file. You can then call 
`presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` to show the popover you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm novice in iOS and I'm not sure how to implement your solution. Can you please please help me how to do it? Many thanks

Comment: I added the whole DocumentHandler.h code. can you please help?

Comment: I added the picture what I need to get.

Comment: OK, I actually decided that I'm staying with QLPreviewController. Now, is there a way that I can customize it? Such as changing the color in the toolbar? Rather than having white color? Also, my last question, is there a way to customise it, so the QLPreviewController will have text search functionality similar to the one in iBooks? Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: No, `QLPreviewController` is not customizable. You can use an `UIWebView` to show the document you're interested in and build the UI you want around it, though. It supports the same document types as Quick Look.

Comment: I was actaully able to change the navbar background color using `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` How can I use text search within `QLPreviewController`?

Comment: You cannot do this easily. There is no built-in API for this. If you use UIWebView, though, you can subclass it to add search functionality as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004094/how-can-i-search-in-an-uiwebview

Comment: OK, I Understand, thanks :) IS there a way that I can pass the local pdf instead of calling the URL?

Comment: Of course. On iOS an URL can refer to a local file too.

Comment: Can my code above be re-written to use the local path rather than URL please?

Comment: Oh come on. If the PDF is included in your app bundle, then just use one of the `NSBundle` methods. If it comes from somewhere else you probably already have a path, so you can use `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`. Stack Overflow is not a place where people write your code for you...